# How to communicate with desktop programs with socket in apache isis

Tags: sockets, viewer, isis

I have a desktop program  which communicates with socket, I want to use apache isis as back-end.  is there a demo like the old DND Viewer ?

Comment: Can you explain the use case a little more?   Apache Isis has its REST API, so if you just want to leverage the business domain from your desktop app, maybe this would suit?

Comment: Yes, I know the REST API. I need a real-time monitoring program.  I have a   desktop program  which communicates with socket. I want to re-develop its server-side and use Apache isis .I noticed that the NakedObjectsFramework has a DnD Viewer, is Apache Isis also have a similar one ? What should I do ?

Comment: As you probably know, Apache Isis is the successor to the Naked Objects framework - the code was donated to the ASF and the name changed, back in 2010.  Along the way one of the things we dropped was the NOF's DnD viewer.  Several reasons for that, one being the complexity of supporting a client/server architecture.  So, the short answer answer is, no, Apache Isis doesn't have anything similar to the old DnD viewer.  I am considering developing a JavaFX viewer which would use the REST API, but haven't done any work on it to date.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the JavaFX viewer may be what I want in the future, I will always pay attention!